# Amazon S3 .net SDK - Delete multiple objects in one request

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

According to the [official guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjectsUsingNetSDK.html) in amazon's website I should be able to do something like that:

```
DeleteObjectsRequest multiObjectDeleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest();
multiObjectDeleteRequest.BucketName = bucketName;

multiObjectDeleteRequest.AddKey("<object Key>", null); // version ID is null.
multiObjectDeleteRequest.AddKey("<object Key>", null);
multiObjectDeleteRequest.AddKey("<object Key>", null);
```

But in my code multiObjectDeleteRequest dose not have the AddKey() method. It only has the a single Key property.

I am using the latest SDK.

Where is the AddKey() method gone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad...
I was using DeleteObjectRequest instead of DeleteObjectsRequest.